# Unable to receive data from Kafka to Spark streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to generate some random data through kafka producer using java code in eclipse IDE. I receive the same data in kafka consumer which also created using java code in the same IDE. My work depends upon streaming data. So, I need spark streaming to receive the random data generated by kafka. For spark streaming, I am using python code in jupyter-notebook. To integrate kafka with spark, "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0.jar" file has to be added to the spark jar. I also tried to add the jar file in pyspark. Here is my spark code

```
import time
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
n_secs = 3
topic = "generate"
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
        .appName("kafkaStreaming") \
        .config("/home/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.0.0.jar") \
        .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, n_secs)
kStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {
                        'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092',
                        'group.id':'test-group',
                        'auto.offset.reset':'latest'})
lines = kStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
words = lines.flatmap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
print(words)
ssc.start()
time.sleep(100)
ssc.stop(stopSparkContext=True,stopGraceFully=True)
```

In the above code, I have added the jar file using SparkSession.config() method. After creating DStream, I am trying to receive data from kafka using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream() by providing topic name, bootstrap servers and so on. After that, I convert the data into rdd and print the result. This is the overall flow of my work. At first, I was executing kafka producer code in java and it generates some data and consumed by kafka consumer. Upto this, it was working properly. While executing the spark streaming code in python, it shows some error like this

```
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/home/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving

Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-873ece723182> in <module>
     36                         'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092',
     37                         'group.id':'test-group',
---> 38                         'auto.offset.reset':'latest'})
     39 
     40 lines = kStream.map(lambda x: x[1])

~/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py in createDirectStream(ssc, topics, kafkaParams, fromOffsets, keyDecoder, valueDecoder, messageHandler)
    144             func = funcWithoutMessageHandler
    145             jstream = helper.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler(
--> 146                 ssc._jssc, kafkaParams, set(topics), jfromOffsets)
    147         else:
    148             ser = AutoBatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())

~/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    334             raise Py4JError(
    335                 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}".
--> 336                 format(target_id, ".", name))
    337     else:
    338         type = answer[1]

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o270.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler
```

Please anyone help me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 0):

There are few things I can see from code itself:

- your jar artifact is for spark 3.0 and you are using spark version 2.4.6.(hint: the last 3 digits in filename are spark version)
- you have added your jar file in your config option. I would suggest first verify if the jar file you are using is the one you need by using it in spark-submit command as `--jar <jar-file-path>` .
- try to print your direct stream first rather than doing all sorts of transformation on it. You can do:

```
kStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {
                        'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092',
                        'group.id':'test-group',
                        'auto.offset.reset':'latest'})
kStream.pprint()
ssc.start()
# stream will run for 50 sec
ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(50)
ssc.stop()
sc.stop()
```

- Once you verify you are getting your data, you can use foreachRDD, transform or other apis to work on your data